# Qt / C++ FireBase only works in Debug Mode

Tags: android, c++, qt, firebase

I'm trying to make Firebase work on Qt ([based on this link](https://medium.com/@shigmas/push-notifications-in-qt-for-ios-and-android-50c2f9a38444)).

When I deploy on 'Release mode', the application crash as soon the firebase is initialized. **The strange thing is that sometimes works using debug mode**.

That are my steps ([based on this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/cpp/client))

1) Create a firebase app object,

```
void FBListener::start_interface()
{
    _jniEnv = new QAndroidJniEnvironment();
    QAndroidJniObject jniObject = QtAndroid::androidActivity();
    ::firebase::App *instance = ::firebase::App::GetInstance();

    if (instance) {
        _app = instance;
    } else {  
        _app = ::firebase::App::Create(*_jniEnv, jniObject.object<jobject>());
    }        
}
```

2 - Initialize

```
static ::firebase::InitResult _InitializeMessaging(::firebase::App *app, void *)
{
    NotificationHandler *handler = NotificationHandler::GetInstance();
    return ::firebase::messaging::Initialize(*app, handler->GetListener());
}

void FBListener::InitializeMessaging()
{
    // I think that the problem is here
    _initializer.Initialize(_app, nullptr,_InitializeMessaging);
}
```

3 - Here the app crashes, if working on release mode. If is on debug mode, I get the token.

```
FBListener::FBListener()
{    
    start_interface();
}
```

This is the github with the code that I'm using [github](https://github.com/driftfloyd/QtFirebase)

Can someone point me a direction?

**My Setup:**

- Qt creator 4.3.1 - Qt 5.9.0
- Java version "1.8.0_131"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
- Android build SDK - android-24
- Mobile Android: 4.4.2 - Google Play Services 11.3.02 - ABI:armeabi-v7a
- Android Studio:

**Sdk Platforms and Tools:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved moving the `QAndroidJniObject jniObject` to the header:

header:

```
private:
    QAndroidJniObject jniObject;
```

cpp:

```
void FBListener::start_interface()
{
    ...
    jniObject = QtAndroid::androidActivity();     
    _app = ::firebase::App::Create(::firebase::AppOptions(), *_jniEnv, jniObject.object<jobject>());

}
```